# Stylelint: Create a regex to prevent parent level html ,body tags

Tags: css, eslint, lint, stylelint

I am trying to create a css rule that prevents css to be applied on body, html rahe
For e.g.

```
body, html {
height: scrollable;
}
```

I am using stylelint as my linter and unable to think of a way to create a rule so that the builds errors out if someone has added a code to parent level tags

Comment: You can use [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) as global values. You could also set styles for the particular elements that differ from the body or html styles. Of course, if the styles are set with JS after loading, then JS will win overall. I'm not overly familiar with Styleint, but it appears to work on their platform...although the entire purpose of Styleint is styles...so it seems counterproductive.

Comment: @Kat The main objective is to throw link error or make the build fail/stop, if someone has put style of body and html rather than overriding the actual values

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [selector-disallowed-list](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/selector-disallowed-list) rule in Stylelint to disallow selectors.

As the rule accepts an array of strings, you can configure it like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "selector-disallowed-list": ["body", "html", "body, html"],
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me try that first